# Sbt: why does it need scala-lang 2.10.3?

Tags: scala, sbt

My build.sbt:

```
import android.Keys._

android.Plugin.androidBuild

name := "teacher-journal"

scalaVersion := "2.11.0"

proguardCache in Android ++= Seq(
    ProguardCache("org.scaloid") % "org.scaloid"
)

proguardOptions in Android ++= Seq("-dontobfuscate", "-dontoptimize", "-dontwarn scala.collection.mutable.**")

libraryDependencies += "org.scaloid" %% "scaloid" % "3.3-8"

scalacOptions in Compile += "-feature"

run <<= run in Android

install <<= install in Android
```

It gives me an error:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3: configuration not found in org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3: 'compile'. It was required from default#teacher-journal-build;0.1-SNAPSHOT provided
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3: configuration not found in org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3: 'compile'. It was required from default#teacher-journal-build;0.1-SNAPSHOT provided
```

Sbt 0.13.2, system scala 2.10.2, java 8, fedora 20. Why does it need scala 2.10.3 and how to fix an error?

Everything works for my friend with similar configuration on Ubuntu.

Comment: Look at teacher-journal-build 0.1-SNAPSHOT for the answer, I'd guess.

Comment: Check the scalaVersion you have selected in the build is the correct (apparently is different from the system one and maybe some plugin/library is requiring a previous one)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed by cleaning ~/.sbt and ~/.ivy2

Comment: when you said clean ... it's something like `rm ~/.sbt/*`

Comment: @delaye Yes, exactly that